# How to plot a grouped bar plot in R with more than one dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, bar-chart

I have two dataframes in R:

```
> dataframe2
   zone   meangpp
1     1 5.4153407
2     2 4.2429236
3     3 4.5719178
4     4 3.1215946
5     5 4.9222054
6     6 3.0384872
7     7 1.9293729
8     8 8.9709741
9     9 7.8904906
10   10 6.6410986
11   12 5.5011823

> dataframe1
   zone     meangpp
1     1 4.050161
2     2 7.729265
3     3 3.408220
4     4 4.884040
5     5 4.258422
6     6 2.906374
7     7 2.241984
8     8 4.703197
9     9 3.617657
10   10 2.712997
11   12 3.589406
```

The zone in both dataframes represents land cover classes.

How can I plot `meangpp` from both dataframes in a bar plot?

Kindly let me know solutions which do not use `ggplot`.

Comment: Have added legend option as an edit to the answer..hope that's useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be:

```
dfnew=merge(df1,df2,by = "zone", all = TRUE)
rownames(dfnew)=dfnew$zone
dfnew$zone=NULL

barplot(t(as.matrix(dfnew)), beside=TRUE)
```

i.e merge, pass as matrix the joined dataframe to barplot function

**Set legend as follows:**

```
colnames(dfnew)=c('df1','df2')
barplot(t(as.matrix(dfnew)), beside=TRUE,legend=colnames(dfnew))
```

**How to merge more than 2 dataframes for this purpose?**

```
dfnew=Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "zone", all = TRUE), list(df1, df2, df3))
```

*NOTE: All are library agnostic, native functions. ggplot or other libraries have not been used in any of the above approaches.*

Comment: for other minor tweaks like legend and colnames etc, refer https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/211-basic-grouped-or-stacked-barplot.html

Comment: Is it possible to merge 3 dataframes together through this code? `dfnew=merge(df1,df2,by = "zone", all = TRUE)`

Comment: yes! dfnew=Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "zone", all = TRUE), list(df1, df2, df3))

Comment: @HallieSheikh edited the answer..so effectively, just create a list of dataframes and pass to the Reduce function. You will be able to merge any number of dfs through this approach

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code

```
library(tidyverse)

dataframe2 = read.table(text="sl zone   meangpp
1     1 5.4153407
2     2 4.2429236
3     3 4.5719178
4     4 3.1215946
5     5 4.9222054
6     6 3.0384872
7     7 1.9293729
8     8 8.9709741
9     9 7.8904906
10   10 6.6410986
11   12 5.5011823", header=T)

dataframe1 = read.table(text="sl zone   meangpp
1     1 4.050161
2     2 7.729265
3     3 3.408220
4     4 4.884040
5     5 4.258422
6     6 2.906374
7     7 2.241984
8     8 4.703197
9     9 3.617657
10   10 2.712997
11   12 3.589406", header=T)

df <- bind_rows("dataframe1" = dataframe1, "dataframe2" = dataframe2, .id = "groups")

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(zone), y=meangpp, fill = groups)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

You can also use `lattice` package like

```
library(lattice)
barchart(meangpp ~ factor(zone),data=df, groups=groups, auto.key = T,
     xlab = "Zone", ylab = "gpp")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ggplot, you have to bind the rows of the 2 data.frames :

```
# impporting your df ####
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~zone,  ~meangpp,
      1, 5.4153407,
      2, 4.2429236,
      3, 4.5719178,
      4, 3.1215946,
      5, 4.9222054,
      6, 3.0384872,
      7, 1.9293729,
      8, 8.9709741,
      9, 7.8904906,
     10, 6.6410986,
     12, 5.5011823
)

df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~zone,  ~meangpp,
      1,  4.050161,
      2,  7.729265,
      3,  3.408220,
      4,  4.884040,
      5,  4.258422,
      6,  2.906374,
      7,  2.241984,
      8,  4.703197,
      9,  3.617657,
     10,  2.712997,
     12,  3.589406
)

# joining them (adding a source id column named country) #### 
big_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(
  df1 %>% mutate(country = 'A'),
  df2 %>% mutate(country = 'B')
)

# the ggplot ####
# planing to fill the bars according to the country variable
ggplot(data = big_df, mapping = aes(x = zone, y = meangpp, fill = country)) + 
  geom_bar(
    stat = 'identity', # so that y is the height of the bars
    position = 'dodge' # so that the bars are side by side (stack to stack them)
  )
```

---